# How to apply properties of an attribute to a div-inherited class?

Tags: css

I have two `table` in two `div`, each `div` having a different class. I would like to apply a `padding` to the cells of one of the tables only.

(the code below is also at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/rv05yo2c/))

The HTML part:

```
<div class=tight>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>hello</td><td>world</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class=wide>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>bonjour</td><td>tout le monde</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The CSS part:

```
td {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

This applies `padding` to all cells. I tried to be specific though various combinations of

```
td .wide { ... }
td, .wide { ... }
td.wide { ... }
```

but I failed to find the right one.

**Is it possible to set a property for an element, but which is a child of a specific `div` (specific = having a specific class)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if you want to apply padding on < td > of the first div, use:

```
.tight td{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

If you prefer to exclude one of the class, you can also use :

```
div:not(.tight) td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some thing like this `.wide td`